# expecting ints or fractions, got % and % in sympy

Tags: sympy, differential-equations

I need to solve differential equation y'=6e^(2x-y).
I am trying to do that in sympy with dsolve().

```
sol = dsolve(Derivative(f(x), x) - 6 *(e**(2*x-f(x))), f(x))
```

But always get error

> expecting ints or fractions, got 7.38905609893065022723042746058 and 6

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get `e` from? It seems you used `math.exp(1)` or similar to get a floating point value that the symbolic package can not treat correctly

Using `sympy.exp` instead works perfectly, even defining `e=sympy.exp(1)` is correctly recognized. Both with the result

```
Eq(f(x), log(C1 + 3*exp(2*x)))
```